# Can't inflate CardView from shared resources

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have 2 apk, main and second with just resources used by first apk. I'm trying to inflate layout

```
mPackName = mContext.getPackageName() + "remote_package_prefix";
mThemeContext = mContext.createPackageContext(mPackName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
mResources = mThemeContext.getResources();
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mThemeContext);
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(mResources.getLayout(getRemoteId(R.layout.remote_layout)), this, true);
```

and got this error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown> 
Caused by:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
Caused by:android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070001
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:887)
at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.initialize(CardView.java:228)
at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:112)
```

**#0x7f070001** is CardView

How to solve this?

**UPDATED** CardView xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/number_item_padding_h"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/number_item_padding_v"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/number_item_padding_v"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/number_item_padding_h"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp" />
```

Comment: Include your layout file XML in this question

Comment: I assume it couldn't find style named "CardView"

Comment: Have you included the gradle dependency (assuming wouldn't compile without it).  Also, have you ensured the versions match the AppCompat version (ie. 23.4.1 for both)?

Comment: As I said, when I launch apk with its activity, all working fine, there is no error. But when I'm trying to get resources from that apk by another apk, I'm getting an  error. Gradle is not working in my Eclipse, so I have included AppCompat and CardView as library projects. I have no troubles with getting libraries work, I'm experiencing troubles only in that particular case, when inflating resources from other apk context

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it work. Just set **cardBackgroundColor** to custom value. I absolutely don't understand why is it not working with default **cardBackgroundColor** value...

In the end I was forced to define my custom CardView style and assign it to each CardView in my layout

```
<style name="AppTheme.CardView" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">2dp</item>
    <item name="cardMaxElevation">2dp</item>
    <item name="cardUseCompatPadding">false</item>
    <item name="cardPreventCornerOverlap">true</item>
</style>
```